# Get asp.net Core mvc modal form response with jquery ajax and update data table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, ajaxform

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC Project. In said project i have a list of resourcetypes in a table:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Id:
            </th>
            <th>
                Name:
            </th>
            <th>
                Tilknyttede Ressourcer:
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var resType in Model.ResourceTypes)
        {
            <tr id="ResourceType@resType.Id" onclick="openResourceTypeNewEditDialog(@resType.Id)">
                <td>
                    <span style="color:@resType.IdColor">@resType.Id</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span>@resType.Name</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @resType.Resources.Count
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

        <!--NewLine-->
        <tr id="ResourceTypeNew" onclick="openResourceTypeNewEditDialog(0)">
                <td>
                    <span style="color:grey;">@Model.NextId</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span>Opret ny Resource type...</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function openResourceTypeNewEditDialog(id)
    {
        var data = {
            ResourceTypeId: id
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Administration/NewResourceType/',
            contentType: 'application/html',
            data: data,
            success: function(content){
                $('#dialogPlaceholder').html(content);
            },
            error: function(e) {}
        })

        $('#dialogPlaceholder').modal();
    }

</script>
```

dialogPlaceholder is just an empty div with the modal and fade classes.

NewResourceType returns the following partial view:

```
<div id="newResourceTypeDialog" class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Ny Resource Type</h4>
    </div>
    <form id="editNewResourceType" asp-action="SaveResourceType" asp-controller="Administration" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="REPLACE-WITH" data-ajax-update="#newResourceTypeDialog">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <label>Id: </label> <input type="text" name="ResourceTypeId" value="@Model.Id" style="color:grey;" readonly></br>
                <label>Navn: </label> <input type="text" id="TxtName" name="Name" value="@Model.Name" placeholder="@Model.Placeholder"/>
            </div>  

        </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Gem" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Luk</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myform").submit(function() { // intercepts the submit event
      $.ajax({ // make an AJAX request
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Administration/SaveResourceType/", // it's the URL of your component B
        data: $("#editNewResourceType").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements
        success: function(content)
        {
            $('#dialogPlaceHolder').modal('toggle');
            alert(bob);
          // show the data you got from B in result div
          alert(content);
        },
        error: function(content){
            alert(content);
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form
    });

  });

</script>
```

However, when i click save, the modal dissappears but the darkening of the screen does not. The Ajax upon submitting returns a row with the filled in data, what i really want to do though is to add the new row, or update if edited in the original table. I guess i could just reload the entire thing by putting it in a partial view, but that seems excessive when it should be possible to just update the single line.